# Class 'lluminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider' not found in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

I am trying to use predis in laravel 5.2.I have installed predis and redis via composer.json in require as predis" :"~1.0".Then I did composer update and also ran composer require illuminate/redis to pull redis files.

but when i am using in my controller(showing only related code)

```
//Code
use Redis;
function index(){
      Redis::set("masterpowers", "Yeah Baby Yeah");
      print_r(Redis::get("masterpowers"));
}
//Code ends
```

Its showing error in localhost as well as in terminal-

> FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:  Class
>   'lluminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider' not found

I have installed redis client too and my command redis-cli ping working fine.

Comment: on your vendor folder under Illuminate folder is Redis directory available?

Comment: Check to make sure you have `'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,` in `config/app.php`, and also that you have `Redis.php` in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Supports/Facades`.

Comment: It should be "predis/predis": "^1.1" in the the composer.json

Answer (score 1):

By default in laravel framework, RedisServiceProvider is already configured in config/app as well as its Facade.

Remove the line of predis in your composer.json and run this:

```
composer require predis/predis
```

You may have missed the actual package by updating the composer.json alone.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your `config/app.php` file that `Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class` is listed under providers, then run terminal command `composer dump-autoload` (regardless if class is found or not).

Comment: I have tried all these.i have checked in my app, the providers and aliases are there.also I have tried composer dump-autoload.Any composer command giving me the same error.

Comment: Delete `composer.lock` file, and empty `vendors` folder, add `"predis/predis": "^1.0",` to your composer.json under "require", then run `composer dumpautoload`, and then `composer update`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike for your response.I have used used Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis; its working but need Redis::connection(); and Redis object.